# Regular expression to return only alpha characters left of a character

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to return only alpha characters `[a-zA-Z]` before a `@` character. E.g.

> abc.123@abc

would return

```
abc
```

> abc.abc@abc

would return

```
abcabc
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your code sample and what regex flavor/lang you're using.

Comment: Is this to get the first component of an email address?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Yes, first part of an email address but only returning alpha characters a-z (no numbers, periods, hyphens etc.)

Answer (score 0):

**Text:**

```
abc.abc@abc
```

**REGEXP:**

```
[\w]+|(?=\@)
```

**Result:**

```
abcabc
```

http://regexr.com/3f0r0

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to return abcabc     (so without the dot)